# How to manage Cross-teams Roadmaps and high level tasks

Tags: release-planning, roadmaps, cross-functional

Do you have any recommendations to track Roadmaps when working with multiple teams and cross-teams projects? Right now we work with Jira and spreadsheets, so any useful templates or tips for combining both would be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to address multiple teams working on a single product? Multiple teams working across a portfolio of products? Teams working on disjoint products or perhaps multiple portfolios?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out Thomas. This is for multiple teams working across a portfolio of products (or workstreams). Sometimes, we have different teams working on the same product, but in other cases, teams are working on disjoint products.

Comment: What problems are you currently facing with those two tools that you think other approaches might help?